# Using FFMPEG To Fill in Gaps of a Raw Audio UDP Stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, stream, vlc, audio-streaming

I have a software defined radio (SDR) that picks up audio from emergency services and with the help of software, streams raw audio using UDP.  The audio is PCM signed 16-bit little-endian.  The UDP stream is also not constant and only has data when audio is detected.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I would like the gaps in recorded audio to be filled with silent or Null audio.  Below are just a couple of my attempts at resolving this:

1. ffmpeg -f s16le -ar 8000 -i udp://127.0.0.1:23456 -af aresample=async=1 -acodec libmp3lame - 
   f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
2. ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i anullsrc -f s16le -ar 8000 -i udp://127.0.0.1:23456 -filter_complex 
   amix=inputs=2:duration=first -acodec libmp3lame -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234

I guess my questions are regarding the best way to resolve this and whether or not ffmpeg can be used in a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order of identify gaps, ffmpeg needs to check timestamps, but a raw stream doesn't have any. So, the workaround is for ffmpeg to assign wallclock time as timestamp at time of reception.

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -sample_rate 8000 -use_wallclock_as_timestamps true -i udp://127.0.0.1:23456 -af aresample=async=1 -acodec libmp3lame -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: After spending more time with this approach I've noticed that it degrades the audio and causes it to have frequent micro stutters.  The audio is much more clear without the timestamps and aresample portion.  Can this be resolved?  Again thanks for your help!

Comment: I was able to correct the issue mentioned in my previous comment by adjusting the value of the min_hard_comp flag.

Comment: @wallace I have similar situation: Opus audio is captured from push-to-talk software, then decoded into f32be raw PCM and fed into ffmpeg/ffplay via STDIN. The PCM audio may contain huge gaps (it's present only when someone talks), and ffplay stops producing sound afterbig gaps. The solution above works for me only if gaps are quite small. The debug log shows that it doesn't insert silence when the gap is happening, but rather starts to calculate and inserting the silence _when the gap ends_. This results in first 30-40 seconds of audio right after the gap just being dropped. Any clues? Thanks

Comment: Filters operate on a frame by frame basis. aresample only knows it has to plug the gap when it receives the next frame and calculates the interval from the prior frame.

Comment: @Gyan thanks for explanation! Is there posibility to insert the silence in other way using FFmpeg (like merging with silent stream or smthng), or this can only be handled on producing side?